# depth_image to point cloud

Tags: ros, depth-image, depth-image-proc, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I want to convert my depth_image to point_cloud, so I use the package "depth_image_proc".
The depth_image_proc to point_cloud_xyz needs two infos:

1. camera_info (sensor_msgs/CameraInfo)
2. image_rect (sensor_msgs/Image)

The Robot that I used published these infos over the topics. My question is, how can I start this conversation with a roslaunch file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281372/depth_image-to-point-cloud/) by [Henne](https://answers.ros.org/users/32327/henne/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2018-01-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out this [`roslaunch` tutorial from the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UsingRqtconsoleRoslaunch#Using roslaunch).

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0